# How to view a web page served from one computer from another computer

Tags: asp.net, iis, url, dynamic, dns

I am running a website from IIS on one computer and I want to view the web page on another computer. the only way I can do this is by using the ipaddress of the computer with IIS on it but would rather have a url. How can I generate a url or use a domain name from dynamicdns.com. I signed up for an account on that website but dont know how to use it. I dont know how to configure it.

Comment: I believe dynamicdns.com requires paid account for dynamic DNS. I have been using no-ip.com and it works ...

Comment: dynamic dns gives you up to 2 hostnames for free

Answer (score 1):

If the computers are in the same LAN you can substitute the computer's name for the IP. If you want the website to be visible outside the LAN, and accessible according to your dynamicdns.com name, you'll probably have to set up port forwarding on your router so that requests for port 80 are sent to the IP address of your IIS server.

Answer (score 0):

edit your hosts file under Windows/system32/drivers/etc

add the ip and any hostname you want to use, e.g.

```
74.125.19.103 my.hostname.com
```